# Laravel Dusk Get all elements on form

Tags: laravel, laravel-dusk, laravel-dusk2

I am trying to get all elements on form using

```
$formInputElements = $response->elements('.is-form input, .is-formtextarea, .is-form tel, .is-form select');

\Log::info('total elements on form '. count($formInputElements).'   Elements:  '. json_encode($formInputElements));
```

Result:
on local its working fine and return

```
total elements on form 12   Elements:  [{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]
```

but on server (i have setup testing server) its returning

```
total elements on form 0   Elements:  []
```

local and testing servers are same only difference is on server its

```
'--headless',
'--no-sandbox',
```

overall dusk is running fine and there is no environment issue !

Comment: On which server you have that configuration?

Comment: its a testing server on Amazon replica of my local box